# Why is Safari displaying weird symbols instead of HTML content?

Tags: nginx, safari, varnish, cloudflare, hhvm

If you take a look at this page using Safari:

http://m2.monetarylane.com/product-category/women/

You'll see this:

[image: Safari bug]
Every other browser displays the content properly.

This server is using Mercury - which is Varnish + Nginx + HHVM + PHP5-FPM fallback + W3 Total Cache + cloudflare.

I've switched off CSS and JS minification, so it's not that.

Any ideas why Safari is doing this?

Comment: what kind of encoding is applied to your files?

Comment: It should be text/html - if you open it in chrome, internet explorer or firefox the URL works as expected.

Comment: not too sure if your data encoding is corret. nonetheless i recommend fixing these errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fm2.monetarylane.com%2Fproduct-category%2Fwomen%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by some bug in GZIP compression vs. WebKit-based browers (Safari, Chrome/Chromium, new Opera). Solution, that worked for me, was disabling content compression in HHVM side and keeping it enabled only in nginx. It's controlled with GzipCompressionLevel HDF runtime option.

```
Server {
    GzipCompressionLevel = 0
}
```

`hhvm.server.gzip_compression_level = 0` in php.ini also should work, but I haven't tested that yet.

Comment: Nice one - I'll get that changed and get back to you. Makes sense - looks like symbols you see if you open a compressed file with a text editor - i should have clicked.