# Why is my website showing question marks and other strange characters on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, wordpress, themes, responsive

My website is not showing on iPhones. It's working fine on Android devices but when I open it on iPhonesit is showing some unique content like this:

[image: See the Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Hi Football Craz, welcome to our community. This is an encoding issue, you need to either give us the URL of you website OR the code that is being used to generate the page.

Comment: https://sunnyfamilydental.com/

Comment: Football Craz it's not an encoding issue but a compression issue, I would disable compression if possible. This is a setting from your webserver. Also, it's not just iOS but also safari on Mac.

Comment: yes exactly on every apple phone and ipad and macbook

Comment: I need more information, like what kind of Webhosting are you using. Which plugins are installed on WordPress. Without this you can google around, I found a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219048/why-is-safari-displaying-weird-symbols-instead-of-html-content

Comment: plugins which i am using:
Fast Velocity Minify
PageSpeed Ninja
PixelYourSite
Smush
Webcraftic Clearfy – WordPress optimization plugin
Webcraftic Robin image optimizer

Comment: Try disable `PageSpeed Ninja` first, test then if it's not fixed, disable `Fast Velocity Minify` and test again. I'm guessing is either one of them of the combination of them.

Comment: and i am using bluehost

Comment: i disabled but now working

Comment: Something is compressing your pages, and then I think Nginx (on Bluehost) re-compress it as well. You need to find the plugin that is doing compression and disable it or disable compression on Nginx like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779960/how-to-disable-gzip-compression-for-text-html

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code or knowing what you built it with, it's a little hard to tell, but looks like an issue with the character type setting.
Make sure you have a character type set:

Ex:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```